# Log won't print certain messages in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

I am trying to print information to the Logcat but certain messages won't print. Note that I am totally new to Android Studio, but this behavior makes no sense. It will print the `"text detected"` line but won't output `"This is NOT printing"`. I have tried putting before the `"text detected"` line and after it. I have tried commenting out the `"text detected"` line and nothing prints to the Log.

[image: screenshot of behavior]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your filter search box, to see all the log message.

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter` is set to text containing `detect` , so that's why it does not show